# In jsfiddle, it works in pure javascript, But - when I include this in my code, it doesn't work without jquery included

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/c2o4j8fz/1/  - Where i get the code.

My code:

```
const chk = document.getElementById('chk');
const body = document.body;
$(function(){
    chk.addEventListener('change', () => {
        $('.body').toggleClass('dark');
        localStorage.setItem("blockIsActive", $('.body').hasClass('dark'));
    }) 
    var blockIsActive = localStorage.getItem("blockIsActive") 
    if (blockIsActive == "true") {
        $('.body').addClass('dark');
    }
});
```

My code displays this error *$ is not defined* in the console, until i add jQuery, but in the jsfiddle example, it works in pure js. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your fiddle has jQuery installed as a resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the Resources tab of that fiddle, it actually says it includes jQuery:

[image: Screenshot of Fiddle meta]

Mind that `$` isn't standard JavaScript, but a jQuery function/API to start with.

Comment: That is a comment and a vote to close

Comment: I tried rewrite it on pure js, but it doesn't work, i tried this code, what's wrong here? alert return "true"
***chk.addEventListener('change', () => {
 document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
    localStorage.setItem("blockIsActive", document.body.classList.contains('dark'));
});

let blockIsActive = localStorage.getItem("blockIsActive");

alert(blockIsActive)

if (blockIsActive == "true") {
    document.body.classList.add('dark');
}
***

Comment: @Alabaika If it's a different issue, make a new question. You'll also have to better explain your code, what you've tried and what the (un)expected results are.

Comment: If someone need the code on poor js - *** chk.addEventListener('change', () => {
 document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
    localStorage.setItem("blockIsActive", document.body.classList.contains('dark'));
});

let blockIsActive = localStorage.getItem("blockIsActive");

if (blockIsActive == "true") {
    document.body.classList.add('dark');
}
*** that start working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you open Resources tab in the left menu you will see that jquery-2.1.4.min.js is included. So you have to include jQuery to get your code working.